# To create a apple script to change the name of the computer with out prompting for admin

Tags: shell, applescript

I am attempting to create a script that will grab the serial number of the Mac and set it to the HostName, LocalHostName, & ComputerName with out it prompting for administrator credentials. So far this is what I have and trying to work through it.

How do I put the credentials in the script to where it pulls the info without prompting?

```
set sys to do shell script "/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType " without altering line endings

set StringVariable1 to "Serial"

set Serial_Number to do shell script "/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ { print $NF }' "


do shell script "scutil --set HostName " & Serial_Number with administrator privileges
do shell script "scutil --set LocalHostName " & Serial_Number with administrator privileges
do shell script "scutil --set ComputerName " & Serial_Number with administrator privileges

display dialog "The Mac has been renamed to " & Serial_Number
```

Comment: `man scutil` says `The --set option requires super-user access.`. Do you really expect that Apple lets you change security relevant system settings without admin access?

Comment: No, I was curious if there was a way to set the username and password in the script itself to use and bypass

Comment: `do shell script` provides parameters to pass user name and password.